# TFS Waiting for Service to Start

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I'm using TFS Express and trying to set up the environment.  I create the project and then it hangs saying its 'Waiting for Service to Start"

What service is it waiting for to start?

Comment: Is your TFS configured well?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check TFS Background Job Agent service is running or not.
2. Check Event log in Event Viewer to see whether there is useful information.